# Wide back box with central 1-gang mounting

Tags: electrical, product-recommendation

Does anyone make a back box that has (British) standard 1-gang lugs, but the actual box extends beyond that?

i.e. something could be mounted centrally with 1-gang spacing (and it would cover the whole box) but the box would have more space either side of that.

Does anything like that exist? Closes I've found is dual 1-gang boxes, where two sit side by side, that would be OK except that I need the 1-gang spaced mounting to be central, or else the box probably wouldn't be covered one side.

Comment: What we yanks do is have a 2-gang box with a 1-gang *mud ring*, but the mud ring concept relies heavily on our use of **drywall** for walls, which in turn hangs on our abundant supply of timber.

Comment: While product-rec questions are off-topic on the Stack due to how quickly markets can change...are you trying to surface-mount or flush-mount this box, and what sort of wall are you mounting it to?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Are they? That tag should probably be removed then. I hoped it was OK because I was more asking if the product I'm describing exists than.. 'what's the best hammer' or whatever. Flush mount, wanted to replace an existing 1-gang back box for more space in the (plasterboard) wall.

Answer (score 1):

You can get various conversion patresses which will fit over a flush 1-gang box and present a surface 2-gang box, eg

[image: British General type 910 conversion pattress 20 mm deep]

and conversion sockets, eg

[image: socket converter 1 to 2 gang double 13 amp socket]

If you want to fit a single socket on a double box you'd probably need to use a Euro module faceplate, Euro module socket and blanking plates

[image]

If you just need a decorative cover then 'finger plates' are available in white or clear

https://cpc.farnell.com/pro-elec/pel00515/finger-plate-for-light-switch/dp/PL10027

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for the opposite: 2-gang space in the wall, and mounting points for a 1-gang plate (which has a big enough ... 'flange' to cover the whole thing as long as fairly central).

Comment: That would be the Euro module option then, or if you can make up the accessory you need using a double Grid switch plate. What are you trying to fit on a double back box that is only available in single format?